# Can an Azure SQL with shard management have databases in different regions?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-elasticpool, azure-elastic-sharding

The documentation for shard management using the Elastic Database Tools seems to imply that all the database instances must be in the same Elastic Pool, and therefore on the same database VM instance. I want to have Azure SQL instances in different regions around the world so I can put the customer records in nearest location possible for reduce latency. Is this actually possible?

Comment: Have you considered Cosmos DB instead? It may be cheaper. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/global-dist-under-the-hood

Comment: No really an option. Switching our live production system from Azure SQL to Cosmos, or any other database, is to risky and to much work.

Comment: @PhilWright it's very hard to answer if it's possible. We don't know how to test it. I  contacted with Azure Support team, what they could told me  is that the database shard  is only supported in the single SQL server, the  Azure SQL instances in different regions or SQL server  is not supported. To get the more effective help, you need call the Azure Support for yourself.   Do I need to post this as answer?